# Building a list in KDB+ / q

Tags: kdb

In KDB+/q how can I get a list of lists using the `til` function? Simply passing a list to `til` is insufficient as it gives a `'type` error;

```
q) til 2 3
'type
```

My desired output from the above would be

```
q) til something 2 3
1 2
1 2 3
```

How does one acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use each to achieve this

```
q) til each 2 3
0 1
0  1 2
```

Comment: So simple. I was faffing around with \: and /: but forgot each... I'm just starting out with Q.